# Strange line appearing under h2 within footer

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header

I seem to have a strange line that appears under one of my headers, H2.

Code used was from mail chimp to input a subscribe form within the footer
and automate the subscribe process.

Here is the code:

```
  <div id="mc_embed_signup">
  <form action="*" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

  <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
  <h2>Want some inbox loving?</h2>
  <h3>Sign up for Cute Pink Boutique new brand clothing releases and 
  news</h3>

  <div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk"> </span>
    </label>

  <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">

  </div>
</div>
```

Also, to give you a better idea, here is a screenshot of the line under the header.

The platform is wordpress.

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enmjH.png)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The code provided by you does not reproduce the problem you have mentioned. I reckon the pink line is because of the CSS associated with the form.

Answer (score 0):

Check the css of the header element by right clicking on it with to inspect the element. It must be having the attribute of either border-top or border-bottom i.e

```
#mc_embed_signup_scroll h2{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

So find out

Comment: Yes, I was using inspect on the header 2. I found out that the header 3 (underneath) had this code causing it: 

.beta+h3, h2+h3 {
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    padding-top: .5407911001em;
}

Thanks for your help

Comment: Wow, am glad that help, please mark my answer as correct